# check box value is not reflecting when using 'if(isset($POST[''])) '

Tags: php

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Notification Views</label>
<div class="controls">

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($POST ['n_index'])){ echo "checked!";}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Teachers
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="2" <?php if(isset($POST ['n_index'])){ echo "checked!";}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Parents

    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="3" <?php  if(isset($POST ['n_index'])){ echo "checked!";}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Management  

    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="4" <?php  if(isset($POST ['n_index'])){ echo "checked!";}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Office 

    </label>
    <?php echo form_error('n_index'); ?>
</div>
```

it is the code and the check box is not getting the value. form submit is taking place and the method is post.
please help some one.

Comment: You should check the index of `n_index`. Also is `checked!` the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

**Replace $POST with $_POST.**

Example.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['n_index'])){ echo "checked!";}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Notification Views</label>
<div class="controls">

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST ['n_index']) && in_array('1', $_POST ['n_index'])){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Teachers
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="2" <?php  if(isset($_POST ['n_index']) && in_array('2', $_POST ['n_index'])){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Parents

    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="3" <?php   if(isset($_POST ['n_index']) && in_array('3', $_POST ['n_index'])){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Management  

    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="4" <?php   if(isset($_POST ['n_index']) && in_array('4', $_POST ['n_index'])){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>  class="a1" title="Choose"> Office 

    </label>
    <?php echo form_error('n_index'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i checked the above one,but it is not reflecting

Comment: I tried with the above code and its working fine at my end. Either share the whole code or the error that you are getting.